# How to get/search results via json from website inputbox id

Tags: json, database, search, get, request

I am unsure why  a get request would not work- 
How would I need to structure the code to get the result true or false:

None of the google results answered my question

tried to implment a get request for the website but did not return the result

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head id="j_idt2">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

   // website to search is for instance dogs.com and inputbox id = dogsearch 
        //
            var stringtosearch = "Dashhound"
            var found = false
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("www.dogs.com/#dogsearch").on("change", function() {
                    var id = this.value;
                if (stringtosearch == id) {
                    found = true
                }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        method: "get",
                        data: "id=" + stringtosearch,
                        success: function(response) {
                            var datashow = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                            $("input#total").val(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML("Result" & found);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       Return json results: Will return found = True/false
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expect that the result would return either true or false as the get request should either fail or find...

It doesn't as the get request just does nothing which is not what I expected

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately we aren't able to help you if you don't provide us with your code.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to do here. You have a change event listener attached to an element called **dogsearch** (which isn't defined in your html) - anyway, on change it compares it's value with stringtosearch -> what should happen if it's true?

Comment: I want the inputbox of the element dogsearch to run a get request ie. change event for the variable = "dashhound" if found it should return true. if not false and update the user in the body of html

Comment: dogsearch is the element tag of the inputbox on the website dogs.com - it is not contained in my html/script.